# Query button organization

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database with a subform attached to a query, and that query has 15 column in it. Fields such as ProjectName, CustomerName, ProjectDueDate, EngineerDueDate, ProjectComplete, EngineerComplete.

What I'd like to do is figure out how to make it automatically organize this data with a click of an action button. The action button would say "List by complete" and that would make sure all fields with the project complete checked as yes stay at the bottom, and from there organize them by due dates (ProjectDueDate & EngineerDueDate) where the closer to now it is, the higher on the list it'll be.

How would I go about doing this?

I have Access 2013, on Windows 7.

The query name is SearchQ, the button name would be ListCompleteBtn, the three fields are called ProjectDueDate, EngineerDueDate, and ProjectComplete.

ProjectComplete>ProjectDueDate>EngineerDueDate.

So, an example list here is this:

```
ProjectName | ProjectDueDate | ProjectComplete | EngineerDueDate |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test1       | 25/10/2013     | [y] (check mark)|24/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test2       | 30/10/2013     | [n] (blank box) |26/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test3       | 30/10/2013     | [n]             |25/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test4       | 25/10/2013     | [y]             |25/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

would be formatted into this when you click the List by complete button:

```
ProjectName | ProjectDueDate | ProjectComplete | EngineerDueDate |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test3       | 30/10/2013     | [n]             |25/10/2013       |  
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test2       | 30/10/2013     | [n]             |26/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test1       | 25/10/2013     | [y]             |24/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
Test4       | 25/10/2013     | [y]             |25/10/2013       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty basic SQL question, so you might want to consider buying (or borrowing) a book on an intro to Access and/or SQL.  What you're looking for is the ORDER BY clause of a SQL string.  You would have to set the RecordSource of your subform with the On_Click event of your button.  Something like:

```
Private Sub ListCompleteBtn_Click()

Forms![MyForm].[MySubform].Form.RecordSource = "Select * from MyQuery ORDER BY ProjectComplete, ProjectDueDate, EngineeringDueDate ASC"
Forms![MyForm].[MySubform].Form.Refresh

End Sub
```

Obviously, [MyForm] is the name of your main form (take out the brackets when you put it in there) and [MySubform] is the name of your subform (using the same substitution as above).  Edit the rest of the SQL statement where appropriate.

If you want to change the sort order, change the "ASC" (short for Ascending) to "DESC" (short for Descending)

Comment: It works, though it seems it doesn't matter if I put ASC or DESC; the project complete check boxes are always sorted to be yes on top, no on bottom.

Comment: Also, I need it so if it is being organized by ProjectComplete DESC (meaning if it's complete and the checkbox is checked in the query, it'll be on the bottom on the list) that ProjectDueDate and EngineerDueDate will both be sorted by date, closer to now on top. That's the hard part, that I can't seem to figure out... having it sort two different ways for three different fields.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can do "ORDER BY OneValue ASC, AnotherValue, ThirdValue DESC".  Just make sure there's a comma after the first sort order, whether you use ASC or DESC first.  You MAY have to do it like "ORDER BY OneValue ASC, AnotherValue DESC, ThirdValue DESC" and have commas after each sort order.  I see that you're pretty new, so If you find this answer helpful please remember to upvote the answer or give it a checkmark.  It helps future users of the site and helps me too.  :o)

Comment: I was going to upvote & checkmark it, though I had this problem with the sub sorting aha. It seems to be sorting the dates after the checks now correctly, except backwards. No matter if I put ASC or DESC 

`code`ORDER BY ProjectComplete DESC, ProjectDueDate ASC, EngineerDueDate"`code`

it seems to be organizing it backwards from what I want; the dates further away on top and dates closer to now on bottom.

Comment: Do you have a sort command after EngineerDueDate?  What you put above has none.  Try adding "ASC" after EngineerDueDate.

Comment: Okay! I am quite dumb for forgetting that part of the code aha. Thank you for all your help, the problem is fixed. :) Much love!